# How do I use Command Prompt to Find only execuatable files in drive C

Tags: command, command-prompt

I need to search for possible virus in drive c. I believe it is in .exe format.

Please advice on how to use command prompt to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a list of exe files.

```
dir c:\*.exe /s >"%userprofile%\desktop\exelist.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above will not search all dirs/folders, try cd %userprofile%
and then

```
for /r /d %G in ('*.exe') DO echo Found Exe : %I
```